# Google translate is not working in android webview

Tags: android, google-translate

I used google translate for translating my web page in to other languages that is working fine .I used the same url in my android application webview but the google translate is not showing inside the site.

Please any one help me with this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show your Webview code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer

I forgot to enable the javascript in web view now working fine

Thanks for all answers

Comment: @ krishna can you tell me how you use translate api in webview?

Comment: this : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_google_translate.asp